# How to add static library to pod dependencies

Tags: cocoapods, static-libraries, podspec

I am trying to distribute my pod (only C files) with Cocoapod. My code depends on a static library (.a), and I am able to correctly build it. But when launching 'pod lib lint' to validate the podspec it gives me the following error:

> *fatal error: 'openssl/aes.h' file not found*

So it doesn't find the header files of the static library.
This is my Podspec file

```
  spec.source_files  = "myPod/*.{c}", "myPod/include/*.h", "myPod/include/openssl/*.h"
  spec.preserve_paths = "myPod/*.{c}", "myPod/include/*.h", "myPod/include/openssl/*.h"
  spec.ios.vendored_libraries = "libs/libcrypto.a", "libs/libssl.a"
  spec.xcconfig = { "HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" => "$(SRCROOT)/myPod/include", 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => "$(SRCROOT)/libs/**" }
```

The missing header files are the ones in   *myPod/include/openssl* , so they should be found.
How can I solve it?